# Location name detection in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, geolocation

I am working on a angular application in which i need to detect location name. I am using geolocation library to detect coordinates. Please suggest me how i get location name.

Answer (score 0):

you can get location from google providing lat and lng by reverse geocoding..

you can sent a get req at this link
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=YOURLAT,YOURLANG&result_type=locality&key=YOURKEY

for more details 
go Through
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding